# How to check if Items already exist in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to prevent if the new enter barcode already in the datagridview and if is exist add the quantity or sum.

Comment: Provide your code related to the `DataGridView` in question, along with the data to check for condition. You seem to be around SO for a while, you should know this by now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to my question

```
Boolean found = false;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox1.Text))
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                string conbarcode = this.textBox1.Text;

                conbarcode = this.textBox1.TextLength == 10 ? this.textBox1.Text : Convert.ToDouble(this.textBox1.Text).ToString("0000000000").ToString();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(conbarcode))
                    {
                        // row exists
                        found = true;

                        row.Cells["qty"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["qty"].Value) + 1;
                        row.Cells["qty"].Selected = true;
                        //MessageBox.Show("Row already exists");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found)
                {
                    this.textBox1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the barcode column like datakey and search if the value exists using Datagrid.Rows.Find ([barcode value]) when you want add new row

Answer (score 1):

Try This Tested Code Call dataGridview_CellEndEdit Event :

```
    private void GvOpStock_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex != 0) 

                for (int row = 0; row < GvOpStock.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
                {

                    if (GvOpStock.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value != null &&
                        row != e.RowIndex &&
                        GvOpStock.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.Equals(GvOpStock.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value))
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
                        return;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //Add To datagridview

                    }

                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```